# How to determine if an NSSet contains touches for a specific control?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsset

This may seem like a stupid question, but what message do i send to the NSSet class to determine how many times a particular control has been tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSSet is a container like an array, it has no inherent information about the content stored inside it, other than the actual content itself, what is inside the NSSet?

Comment: I figured it out thanks to your help. I needed to use containsObject. Thanks!